# CSS :hover Selector not working as expected with gifs

Tags: css

I am working on a new button styles and currently facing a challenge: my `<button>` CSS `:hover` selector is not behaving as expected.

All attempts to making it work have proven futile.

How can I possibly achieve that effectively?

Below is my code:

```
.button_depression {
    background: url(http://67.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9atx55D6F1qd1e6no1_400.gif)
no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.button_depression:hover {
    background-color: #959595;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `background` for your *hover*; not `background-color` as illustrated in the snippet below:

```
.button_depression:hover {
    background: #959595;
}
```

#### Brief summary:

**background** [CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) is a shorthand to set the values for one or more of: background-clip, background-color, background-image, background-origin, background-position, background-repeat, background-size, and background-attachment.

When working without the shorthand, the `background-image` property supersedes `background-color` and as such, setting `background-color` alone without abnegating it (`background-image`) will result in its precedence.

In other words, `background-image: none;` in combination with `background-color: #959595;` will work. *(Refer to snippet below)*

```
.button_depression:hover {
    background-color: #959595;
    background-image: none;
}
```

*(`background-image: unset;` works well too, but can't tell if supported by all browsers)*

Note that you can be achieved the same, using the *background* shorthand, simply as above, with *`background: #959595;`* (which I prefer: simple, less verbose, same result).

*More details [here ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)*.

Comment: Because `background-image` supersedes `background-color` and as such, setting `background-color` alone without abnegating it (`background-image`) will result in its precedence. In other words, `background-image: none;` *(`background-image: unset;` works well too, but can't tell if supported by all browsers)* in combination with `background-color: #959595;` will work. Same can be achieved simply as above, with `background: #959595;` (which I prefer: simple, less verbose, same result). More details [here ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: You should probably put that in your answer.

Comment: Just updated my answer, with detailed explanation and reference as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Idk why I was getting downvoted but I appreciate the time you put into the answer!

Comment: I couldn't have explained it better. Background supercedes background-color and therefore, background-color appears 'behind' the used background-image. Right?

Comment: Nope! **background** is a just a shorthand that enables you reference many other `background-*` properties. `background-image` rather supersedes `background-color` (as `background-color`, just as [borders](https://developer.mozilla.org/cn/CSS/border), is rendered below the `background-image`. *(See `background-image` as an object placed on top of `background-color`)*

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the button hover changing the background color due to the background image. You can set the button image to None on hover and then change the color. This might be what you want. Alternatively you can just set background to the background color you wanted. Your preference how you want to acomplish this.

```
.button_depression {
    background: url(http://67.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9atx55D6F1qd1e6no1_400.gif) no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.button_depression:hover {
    background: None;
    background-color: #959595;
}
```

Comment: Is `None` a valid property value?

Comment: Yeah. Oddly enough it is. Rarely used, and there are better ways to solve this user's question, but he can use None to fix the issue without rewriting a lot of his code.

Comment: I think it's `none` with a lower-case `n`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I tested it out before answering the question and 'None' seemed to work just fine. Maybe the CSS interpreter allows us to use 'None.'